# How to parse a datetime string as current default timezone using Carbon?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have a date time string that isn't in my current timezone: `2019-08-18T10:01:02Z`

I need to have a Carbon version of this string.

When I simply do: `(new Carbon("2019-08-19 00:37:46"))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

It spits out: `2019-08-18 10:01:02`

I need it to get the value `2019-08-18 06:01:02` (representative of the end-user application's set timezone).

Is there a way to do this without specifying the timezone when calling Carbon? e.g. without doing `Carbon::parse($file->getClientModified())->tz('America/New_York')`.

For example, I know `strtotime` takes in to account the timezone and thus: `Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime($str))` will work, but I feel like there must be some internal function that can do this that I am unaware of.

*Basically, I am trying to avoid calling `date_default_timezone_get()` or getting some configuration variable everywhere.*

The timezone is set normally via `date_default_timezone_set()`.

Comment: what is the first date time string timezone ? and is it always from same timezone or it changes in different cases?

Comment: always the same

Answer (score 4):

You can [pass a second parameter to the constructor](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-instantiation), to specify the timezone.

E.g:

```
$carbon = new Carbon('2019-08-19 00:37:46', 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

If you want to change it application-wise, just do it during your application bootstrapping. In your application [service provider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/providers#introduction) you can do the basic boostrapping in the [`boot()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/providers#the-boot-method).

E.g.:

```php
public function boot() {
     date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
}
```

Comment: I am aware of that method, as well as the `tz` method as shown in the above code. "Is there a way to do this without specifying the timezone when calling Carbon?" e.g. looking for something like (not actual function) `Carbon::createUsingCurrentTimezone($str)`. all these timezone methods require me to actually have the timezone and I don't feel like calling `date_default_timezone_get()` everywhere.

Comment: You could call `date_default_timezone_set()` once, during your application service provider `boot` method.

Comment: doesn't laravel do that automatically?

Comment: I'm not sure it does. Since you are already using that configuration, and I'm assuming you've already cleared cache; it appears it doesn't.

Comment: i tried it anyways and it didn't make a difference. before/after making the changes if I echo the timezone I get `America/New_York`. to be clear, this datetime string is coming from an api that I believe uses UTC. i don't think carbon takes in to account the current timezone when not doing things like `Carbon::now()`, probably why only explicitly telling it the timezone works. guess i'll have to continue using strtotime in association with carbon

Answer (score 0):

Update the app.php in config folder and update the timezone there

```
'timezone' => 'America/New_York'
```

Hope this will solve the issue